# How to convert a string into a list of positions in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I currently have data that stores the week numbers associated with named periods as follows in a table with columns PERIOD and DATESTRING

```
PERIOD  DATESTRING
Period1 NNYNYY    //The position of 'Y' indicates a yes, 'N' indicates no
Period2 NNNNNY
...
```

So, since week 3 is part of period 1, there is a 'Y' in position 3 in the datestring for that period.

I need to convert this into a table that has the period in one column, and the positions of the Ys in the next:

```
PERIOD  WEEKNUMBER
Period1 3
Period1 5
Period1 6
Period2 6
...
```

Comment: What database? This is rather dependent on that information.

Comment: Also, how long can this datestring be?  A fairly simple solution is possible for a short string, but a long string would require a different kind of solution.

Comment: datestring can only be 52 characters long.

Comment: You really ought to change the table design if you can. It's almost always a bad idea to be encoding multiple data items in a single column's value.

Comment: This is as part of an attempt to get sensible reports from a third-party solution. Can't change the design, just have to write complex queries to get what we want out of it, and I'm currently being tripped up by this coding scheme for week numbers that they use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining to a table of numbers and using the `substring()` function to get a character at each position:

```
with numbers as (
    select 1 as num
    union all
    select num + 1 from numbers
    where num < 53
)
select period,num from table1
    join numbers on substring(datestring,num,1) = 'Y';
```

This uses a recursive query to build the table of numbers.

[Here it is in SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57df0/1).

I built and tested it on SQL Server 2008, but I don't think it should be a problem to do this in 2005.  You would have to tweak it at most.

Comment: Thanks a million - this was the one remaining hurdle in what has been a relatively simple little project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with a [Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) using [**`charindex`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find `Y`'s ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8f2c/11)):

```
with cte as (
  select period, charindex('Y', datestring) as weeknumber
    from Periods
   where charindex('Y', datestring) <> 0

  union all

  select p.period, charindex('Y', p.datestring, cte.weeknumber + 1) as weeknumber
    from periods p
    join cte on p.period = cte.period
   where charindex('Y', p.datestring, cte.weeknumber + 1) <> 0
)
select * from cte
order by period, weeknumber
```

Comment: +1. Not being a SQL Server user, I wasn't aware of the charindex function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some idea for you. This is Oracle query but I think it should work in any SQL or you can fix it to work in SQL Srv 2005. All functions used are ANSI SQL standard. I'm not sure if there is such thing as LEVEL in 2005...:

```
SELECT 'Period1'||' '||Y_Pos as Y_Pos FROM
(
 SELECT  distinct(Instr('NNYNYY', 'Y', LEVEL)) Y_Pos
   FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Length('NNYNYY') 
ORDER BY 1
)
/

SQL>

Y_POS
----------
Period1 3
Period1 5
Period1 6
```

Comment: SQL Server does not understand `||`, `dual`, or `connect by`.  This is the Oracle equivalent of a recursive CTE.

Comment: @mellamokb, thank you for sharing. I do not know much about SQL Server. I hope there is an equiv. to ||-concatenation as well as connect by, level... The dual is just a table that is available even in Access I think. But any other table can be used in place.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with master..spt_values system table

```
SELECT PERIOD, number
FROM dbo.test29 t
  JOIN master..spt_values v ON v.type = 'P' 
    AND SUBSTRING(DATESTRING, number, 1) = 'Y'
```